# Is it important to use base table in query?

Tags: 7, database, entities

Is it important to use base table for entity in query? For example if I want to get all user's id of specific role, should I do:

```
  $query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->distinct();
  $query->fields('u', array('uid'));
  $query->innerJoin('users_roles', 'r', 'u.uid = r.uid');
  $query->condition('r.rid', 3);
```

or

```
  $query = db_select('users_roles', 'r');
  $query->fields('r', array('uid'));
  $query->condition('r.rid', 3);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not important, nor necessary.

There's no API method for getting this information, so going directly into the database is fair game. Once you're going directly into the database, you only need to include the tables and fields that your data requires - anything else is a waste of resources.

In this case, you don't need to select or filter anything from the `users` table, so there's no need to join it in (unless you're worried about referential integrity, and want to make sure the user record actually exists).

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the second query is enough, unless you need additional filtering/conditions that depend on the base table (e.g. to select only active users).

Generally speaking, core base tables can have certain tags that give you additional processing/filtering out of the box. The best example is the `node_access` tag, which if you add to a query that runs against `{node}` table, will automatically perform node access checks, and fetch only the nodes currently active user has access to. This might be something to consider if you're querying node-related information.

You can read more about query alteration (tagging) [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/310077).